# BIOS not load after efibootmgr editing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-8, bios, efibootmgr

1. I had Windows 8 on my laptop and recently installed Ubuntu on another partition but after that Ubuntu boots directly without any multiple boot selection page and Windows was no reachable.
2. Then I repaired Windows with it's bootable disk but when I return to Ubuntu again Windows become no reachable.
3. So I searched web and read something about efibootmgr and tryed to edit it as root user in terminal of Ubuntu.
4. After restarting laptop, it doesn't boot at all and steys in bios loader page and no keys work, [F2], [F12], [Ctrl]+[Alt]+[Delete] ....

Edit: I opened laptop and disconnected an reconnect motherboard battery and then keyboard works but after key detection too,  stay in that page but with another massage

How can I boot my laptop?

Comment: The initial problem was likely because you installed Ubuntu in Legacy mode and Windows was, correctly, in UEFI mode. Then, using efibootmgr you broke everything. Before anything else open UEFI settings and try to select Windows. If it boots fine, reinstall Ubuntu but this time in the proper UEFI mode.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia BIOS not not load anything and no keys works...

Comment: You have to use the key yiubaued before and spam it immediately after powering on or press it and keep it before powering on. That's an issue with your hardware though, nothing to do with Ubuntu or Windows right now.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I opened laptop and removed motherboard battery, after it keyboard work but after that too, stay there

Comment: I recently had this problem, am currently looking for a fix. It seems the NVRAM/CMOS is messed up. For CMOS, which is powered by it's own battery, I reckon removing it and replugging it may work. For NVRAM I am yet to find at least clue on where to look